# How to automate a textbox where area code of phone number gets added automatically?

Tags: selenium

Scenario is with an eComm website:

Cases are :

1. Open https://www.flipkart.com/
2. Click on Login URL
3. Top Window opens up.
4. Try adding phone number [Don't login using eMail ID]
5. Find a **+91** gets added as a prefix automatically whenever you add a phone number.

I am using Selenium WebDriver and Java for automating this scenario. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to ask here?

Comment: Provide more info as: 1. What worked for you? Show code. 2. Where are you stuck? 3. Provide error stacktrace. 4. Provide relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: Point 1&2 : https://www.screencast.com/t/D8TP2pZTD
Point 3 : https://www.screencast.com/t/rfJpTntjldjH

Comment: FYI https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

Comment: The last comment on the aforementioned URL is mine :) Its not fixed, I guess. So instead of sendKeys, I used JavascriptExecutor to write the numbers on the textbox, but it failed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this. It now works for me with the configuration **FF 53, geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64, Windows 64 Bit and Selenium 3.4.0**

More can be checked here : https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special for this specific case here. Just open up the login window and use the code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[class='_2zrpKA']")).sendKeys("Your phone number goes here");
```

Comment: This will not work. Check the error [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/rfJpTntjldjH)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow we are unable to get Dynamic Xpaths.
Try this absolute path

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("1231");
```

Comment: @Shekhar : Doesn't work. I have attached a error screenshot URL in the other Comments, please check.

Comment: Use this after giving URL. driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); and provide the stack trace for this particular solution .

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Firefox WebDriver and now it got fixed.

Download the latest Gecko Driver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Answer (score 0):

WebElement phone = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id="load_form"]/fieldset[2]/input"));
phone.sendKeys("123456789");

This worked for me!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).